# Algorithm for Contest Schedule

Tags: algorithm

Can you explain the algorithm to solve this problem? http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=6708&rd=10000. The explanation is given here but its hard to understand http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=srm320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not a pity you did not understand the "solution", because it was explained without giving the essential details and... it is incorrect as well.

First of all, there should be no real importance whether you start to search for the optimal solution from the start and going forward or you start the search from the end and go backwards towards the start. Off course, there is a slight difference, because if John manages to finish his tasks on the contest earlier than its end time, then he might be able to still catch the next contest. Therefore, if the direction matters at all, then he should start his planning from the start time and should go forward, as with the end time he might earn the possibility to participate on other contests as well. Let us not dwelve ourselves too deep into the details, as this small difference is not important for this little task, it would only be important in a serious project.

I have been harsh to the solution as I called it incorrect. I will repeat: it is incorrect. If you look again at the pseudo-code and forget about the in-elegant backwards direction (which might be useful in other problems, but not here) you will notice that a contest is chosen or not chosen when you iterate to a time. Imagine the case when there is a contest which takes place in a time span of a day, but John could participate in four other contests in the meantime, so he should choose between participating in the long contest or in the other four contests. Let's suppose that John has a high probability to win the long contest and lower probability to win the other four contests. In the iteration which was given we can only see whether the long contest or the four other contests are the better choices after one or two shorter contests were taken out of contention.

A backtrack solution, by generating all possible scenarios and finding the best choice would certainly solve the problem, but it would have an exponential complexity.

"Then the value of A[s] can be computed backward."
Yes, it can be computed backwards. But is the writer giving ANY reason why should it be computed backwards, why is it a better choice to compute this backwards? No. Yes, it is a common approach in dynamic programming to attack the problem backwards and in many cases there is a reason, but here honestly I do not see any valid reason why should we compute it backwards, as the problem is almost symmetric in time, the only difference between "forward" and "backward" being the start of time and the end of time in question, which are just two constants.

Let's elaborate the example given earlier. Let's suppose that there are five contests:

1. s = 1, t = 24, p = 0.99
2. s = 2, t = 3, p = 0.66
3. s = 4, t = 5, p = 0.66
4. s = 6, t = 7, p = 0.66
5. s = 8, t = 9, p = 0.66

As you see, in each time, contest 1. is more attractive than each of contest 2, 3, 4 and 5. But they together are far more attractive than contest 1.

So, the algorithm having the exponential complexity is much better. It is slow as hell, but hey, it is correct in contrast to the "solution" given. If you want a solution, then you can stop reading here. If you want to hear a much better solution, then read on.

Let's suppose we define the logical operator of "exclusion", which is symmetric. If a contest C1 excludes a contest C2, then C2 excludes C1 as well.

Let's suppose further that while you read the input you are also building up a data-structure holding the exclusion clusters: each cluster would be a maximal set of contests where each C1 and C2 either directly or transitively exclude each-other. You could find the best solution for each cluster with divide et impera and when you know the solution for all the clusters, the only task you need to finish the job is to merge the sub-results to have a whole result.

Comment: "it is incorrect as well" It looks fine to me up to fencepost errors. "you will notice that a contest is chosen or not chosen when you iterate to a time" No, not at all. You're right that the direction doesn't matter, though.

Comment: Have you tried it with my test case?

Comment: Yes, and it works fine because it doesn't do what you say it does.

Comment: The pseudo-code was iterating time with T. So what matches are iterated in the inner cycle? If the implementation is correct, then the answer is not explained well, as we already have two people wondering how it works. I had the impression that the pseudo-code was iterating the contests active on the given iteration of time.